# Way to reference icon in Compass Sprite without including magic selectors

Tags: css, sprite, sass, compass-sass

*This is in particular reference to the Compass spriting framework*

Following the documentation here http://compass-style.org/help/tutorials/spriting/#magic-selectors

I have used this method so that this:

> - selectors/ten-by-ten.png
> - selectors/ten-by-ten_hover.png

```
.edit {
     @include selectors-sprite(ten-by-ten);
}
```

generates:

```
.selectors-sprite, .edit {
   background: url('/selectors-sedfef809e2.png') no-repeat;
}
.edit {
   background-position: 0 0;
}
.edit:hover, .edit.ten-by-ten_hover, .edit.ten-by-ten-hover {
   background-position: 0 -20px;
}
```

which is really great. However, I was wondering If/How in another instance I could include the "ten-by-ten.png" image from the sprite without including the magically attached hover state?

i.e.

I want this:

```
.view {
     background: url('selectors/ten-by-ten.png') no-repeat;
}
```

Where hovering over this icon does not trigger the :hover state (ten-by-ten_hover.png).

But I was wondering if there was a way to achieve this still referencing the sprited image?

Thanks for any help/advice.

Answer (score 2):

You can add sprites directly to an element using the @extend directive. The syntax is @extend .folder prefix - sprite name - state (ie, .selectors-sprite-name_hover):

```
.view {
  @extend .selectors-ten-by-ten
}

  &:hover {
    @extend .selectors-ten-by-ten_hover
  }

  &:active {
    @extend .selectors-ten-by-ten_active
  }
```

Answer (score -2):

.selectors-ten-by-ten_hover, .selectors-ten-by-ten_active, etc returned class not found errors for me in Compass.

This worked however:

.viewHover { @extend .selectors-ten-by-ten:hover; }

.viewActive { @extend .selectors-ten-by-ten:active; }